# ORA-01489 - Result of string concatenation is too long - Append big Varchar columns

Tags: oracle, plsql, append, oracle12c, clob

I'm trying to append 4 columns of data type such as varchar2(4000) || varchar2(4000) || varchar2(4000) || varchar2(100) and try to assign it to a CLOB datatype column of a table.

Something like below,

```
insert into test as select TO_CLOB (A || B || C  || D) as final from test_a;
```

Table-1: Test

```
A CLOB;
```

Table-2: Test_a

```
A varchar2(4000) 

B varchar2(4000) 

C varchar2(4000) 

C varchar2(100)
```

I get the error as `ORA-01489 Result of string concatenation is too long`

I also tried doing separate CLOB conversion something like below, but it takes too long to execute.

```
insert into test 
as select TO_CLOB (A )  || TO_CLOB (B ) || TO_CLOB (C ) || TO_CLOB (D ) ) as final from test_a;
```

Please let me know if there is any other way of doing it.

P.S. I'm using `Oracle 12c version`

Answer (score 1):

An implicit conversion towards clob takes place when one of the parameters of || is a clob, so try the following:

Original query:

```
select rpad('0', 4000, '0')||rpad('0', 4000, '0')||rpad('0', 4000, '0')||rpad('0', 4000, '0')||rpad('0', 100, '0') from dual
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

TO_CLOB in first member of concatenation:

```
select TO_CLOB(rpad('0', 4000, '0'))||rpad('0', 4000, '0')||rpad('0', 4000, '0')||rpad('0', 4000, '0')||rpad('0', 100, '0') from dual
1 row(s) selected
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DBMS_LOB.writeappend` to INSERT CLOB for example like below

```
    declare       
    l_clob clob := '12345';     
    A varchar2(4000):=lpad('A',4000,'A');       
    B varchar2(4000):=lpad('B',4000,'B');     
    C varchar2(4000):=lpad('C',4000,'C');      
    begin       
    dbms_lob.writeappend( l_clob, length(A), A );        
    dbms_lob.writeappend( l_clob, length(B), B );        
    dbms_lob.writeappend( l_clob, length(C), C );       
    insert into test_clob values(l_clob);
    end;
```